# Сколькими способами можно собрать число 40 имея три числа 10 25 15?

Tags: математика, логика, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Сколькими способами можно собрать число 40 имея три числа 10 25 15

**x = 10**

**y = 25**

**z = 15**

Я понимаю что можно написать

**x + z + z равно 40**

**y + z равно 40**

**x + x + x +x равно 40**

Получается: **тремя способами**

Подскажите как это выразить "узнавать" математически.

Comment: ну например `#{x,y,z from Z+}:10x+15y+25z=40` если вас именно короткая запись интересует.

Comment: Пожалуйста опишите более подробно.

Comment: не понятно, что можно делать с числами. Только ли складывать? например, y+y-x тоже будет 40.

Comment: Только складывать.

Comment: Извините но я не знаком с F# и написанное здесь для меня сродни иероглифам. Можете описать решение на любом из языков типа "c++, java, lisp scheme или java script".

Comment: Числа можно только складывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А просто перебором не годится?  http://ideone.com/XcQm0p:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int Count(const vector<int>& x, int sum)
{
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> a(x.size(),0);

    for(;;)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (inner_product(x.begin(),x.end(),a.begin(),0) == sum)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < a[j]; ++k)
                    cout << "+" << x[j];
            }
            cout << " = " << sum << endl;
            ++count;
        }
        do {
            if (a[i]*x[i] <= sum)
            {
                a[i]++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        } while( i < a.size());
        if (i == a.size()) break;
    };
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> x = { 5, 10, 15, 25 };
    cout << Count(x,40) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, это красивей всего решается рекурсиями:

```js
var numbers = [10, 15, 25]

function get(x, path = '', used = 0) {
  // переменную used добавил, чтобы не использовать то, что уже прогорело, чтобы не плодить комбинации одного решения.
  for (var i = used; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    //Перебираем числа:
    num = numbers[i]
    //можно отнять - отнимем и начнем заново:
    if (num < x) get(x - num, path + ' ' + num, i);
    //Остаток равен нулю - путь хорош:
    if (num == x) console.log(path + ' ' + num);
    if (num > x) return false;

  }
}

get(40)
```